# Sudden "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role...:no session or session was closed" - Exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, jsp

in an application that works for quite some time without any change I got the Exception

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ... , no session or session was closed
```

What could be the possible cause, all of a sudden? The method where this happens is tested and used successfully for the past 3 years.

Thanks for the help,
al

P.S. Environment: JSP, Spring, Hibernate, MySQL

Comment: Please can you provide more information like what the class structure is and the stack trace is like for the exception?

Comment: you must have changed something buddy!!

Answer (score 9):

If you pass an entity around and eventually leave the transaction boundary where it was read, you can't access any not already initialized association (I guess yours is something like `Collection<Role> roles`). If you then access `roles` Hibernate might try and intialize it, but since the transaction (and the Hibernate session with it) is closed already, you get that exception.

> The method where this happens is tested and used successfully for the past 3 years.

This just might mean that the case of the collection not being initialized when that method is called is rare and did not happen in the last 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Open Session In View setting in web.xml. It will help if you are trying to send hibernate objects to the spring MVC view and bringing it back.

Two options.

- Load all lazy collections before you close the hibernate session
  or
- Use OpenSession In View setting in web.xml